# Line break inside HTML tag attribute value

Tags: html, mailto, line-breaks, subject

How can I insert line breaks inside HTML attribute values, like this:

```
<href="mailto:info@example.com?subject=TestMail&body=Please enter the following details.
Name
Email
Mob No">
```

When the user replies, the body part should display as below:

```
Please enter the following details.
1. Name
2. Email
3. Mob No
```

I tried using `<br>` tags, but they get displayed.

Answer (score 29):

The line break should be URL encoded into `%0D%0A`

Your mailto will look like:

```
    <a href="mailto:xxx@example.com?subject&body=1.Name%0D%0A2.Email">mailme</a>
```

Info from http://www.cubetoon.com/2008/how-to-enter-line-break-into-mailto-body-command/

Comment: Thanks alot buddy!.. I was afreaid of what to tell my Miss as I was struggling to get this line break done.. U helped me from a big struggle

Comment: This is also specified in the 'mailto' URI Scheme [RFC 6068](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6068#section-5).